# How To Download an Image from public s3 bucket url using Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, image-processing

I want to download a jpg image from s3 bucket public url without using boto3.
I am able to download it, but it is getting downloaded as file rather than jpg format. I am using the following code

```
url = amazon_url
file = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
with open(folder_saving_directory, 'wb') as input_file :
    input_file.write(file.content)
```

How to downlaod it in jpg format only rather than file format.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it is getting downloaded as file rather than jpg format"? JPG is a file type...

Comment: Are you providing the file extension in your ```folder_saving_directory``` variable? For example: ```/path/to/file.jpg```